# Inputstring is null after being set in a static method, why?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, static-methods

I am uncertain of how memory is managed in my particular case...

I have two methods:

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)loadPlist: (NSString*) name
                     andErrorDesc: (NSString*) errorDesc
                        andFormat: (NSPropertyListFormat*) format
                     andplistPath: (NSMutableString*) plistPath
{    
    NSString * destPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

    destPath = [destPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", name]];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destPath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"plist"] toPath:destPath error:nil];
    }

    plistPath = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[destPath copy]];

    NSData * plistXML =
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];

    NSLog(@"AFTER plistPath: \n%@",plistPath);


    return
    (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                            propertyListFromData:plistXML
                            mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                            format:format
                            errorDescription:&errorDesc];
}


+(bool)writeToCache:(NSString*) data andField: (NSString*) field
{
    NSString * errorDesc = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSMutableString * plistPath;
    NSMutableDictionary * temp = [BPUtils loadPlist:@"cache" andErrorDesc:errorDesc andFormat:&format andplistPath:plistPath];

    if (!temp)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
        return false;
    }

    NSMutableArray * arr = [temp objectForKey:field];
    [arr addObject:data];

    NSLog(@"path: %@",plistPath);

    // Write to plist
    bool res = [temp writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"RES: %d", res);

    return true;
}
```

The problem is that the bottom method that sends in "plistPath" to the above method retrives a null plistPath after the above method has set it. Why and how can I fix this?

```
NSLog(@"path: %@",plistPath);
```

in the bottom method shows null, why?

**I use ARC.** Also "destPath" is set and shows the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could be a bit confused here.

You are creating `plistPath` in the bottom method. And then you pass `plistPath` into

```
     [BPUtils loadPlist:@"cache" andErrorDesc:errorDesc andFormat:&format andplistPath:plistPath];
```

but `plistPath` is `NULL`

```
     NSMutableString * plistPath; // Is NULL
```

But once it has been passed in the local `plistPath` takes over.

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)loadPlist: (NSString*) name
                 andErrorDesc: (NSString*) errorDesc
                    andFormat: (NSPropertyListFormat*) format
                 andplistPath: (NSMutableString*) plistPath // Notice the local plistPath variable. This is the one you are playing with in this method.
```

At this point you are setting `plistPath` but remember it is still just a local variable and not an instance variable. So the button method will never know about it being set, as far as the button method is concerned it is still `NULL`

```
plistPath = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[destPath copy]];
```

So whatever you set in `plistPath` in the top method will not get passed back to the bottom method, think of the top `plistPath` as being deallocated when the method does the `return`. 
So the `plistPath` in the bottom method will remain `NULL`

So try this instead **SOLUTION**

```
 static NSMutableString *yourNewStringforPlistPath; //This will be NULL

 +(NSMutableDictionary *)loadPlist: (NSString*) name
                 andErrorDesc: (NSString*) errorDesc
                    andFormat: (NSPropertyListFormat*) format
                 andplistPath: (NSMutableString*) plistPath
 {    
 NSString * destPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

 destPath = [destPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", name]];

 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destPath])
 {
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"plist"] toPath:destPath error:nil];
 }

 yourNewStringforPlistPath = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[destPath copy]];

 NSData * plistXML =
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:yourNewStringforPlistPath];

 NSLog(@"AFTER plistPath: \n%@",yourNewStringforPlistPath);


 return
 (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                        propertyListFromData:plistXML
                        mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                        format:format
                        errorDescription:&errorDesc];
  }


  +(bool)writeToCache:(NSString*) data andField: (NSString*) field
  {
NSString * errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSMutableDictionary * temp = [BPUtils loadPlist:@"cache" andErrorDesc:errorDesc andFormat:&format andplistPath:[NSNull null]]; // As this is already NULL you don't really need to pass yourNewStringforPlistPath in unless in the future this value can be set before this.

 if (!temp)
 {
    NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
    return false;
 }

  NSMutableArray * arr = [temp objectForKey:field];
 [arr addObject:data];

 NSLog(@"path: %@",yourNewStringforPlistPath);

 // Write to plist
 bool res = [temp writeToFile:yourNewStringforPlistPath atomically:YES];

 NSLog(@"RES: %d", res);

 return true;
 }
```

Comment: Is this the behaviour because the method is static? So what is the solution? I want to be able to set it in the top method, does plistPath need to be static aswell?

Comment: @hirre See solution. Notice the `static NSMutableString *yourNewStringforPlistPath`

Comment: don't use `plistPath` this will just create confusion. And the local variable will still override the static one if you use `plistPath` as your static variable.